# excel-vba codes

Tags: excel, vba

can anyone explain me the below codes...

```
Public Sub delay(seconds As Long)
            Dim endTime As Date
            endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
            Do While Now() < endTime
                DoEvents
            Loop
        End Sub

    Function GetText2(ByVal strText, ByVal strStartTag, ByVal strEndTag)
        Dim intStart, intEnd
        intStart = CLng(InStr(1, strText, strStartTag, vbTextCompare))

        If intStart Then
            intStart = CLng(intStart + Len(strStartTag))
            intEnd = InStr(intStart + 1, strText, strEndTag, vbTextCompare)
            If intEnd <> 0 Then
             GetText2 = Mid(strText, intStart, intEnd - intStart)
           Else
              GetText2 = ""
            End If
        Else
            GetText2 = ""
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: There is nothing in that code that can't be understood reading the VBA help. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917334/what-does-the-below-codes-do

Comment: @Remou Also look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916903/what-does-this-code-do-closed

Comment: @belisarius Yep. I have flagged.

Comment: @Abhi: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I have answered your question.  In the meantime, please review our FAQ here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and familiarize yourself with the website and what are considered good, on-topic questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, please don't make any more duplicate user accounts, it just makes more work for us.

Comment: Apropos of not very much, all of the parameters and local variables in GetText2 are of `Variant` type whereas the variable names - e.g. intStart - suggest that they should be more strongly typed. Also, `intStart = CLng(intStart + Len(strStartTag))` is silly - either `lngStart` or `CInt` would be better

Comment: You find the combination of these two code blocks in VBA modules to control an Internet application from Excel - typically I would use them to perform an automated login to a web site based on UN/PW information stored in an Excel list (myself I am using similar code for exactly that purpose)

Answer (score 0):

Abhi, it looks to me like the `GetText2` function accepts three strings, searches for the second and third strings in the first string, and returns the text between the second and third strings.  So for example:

```
GetText2("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog","quick","fox")
```

should return the string:

```
"quick brown fox"
```

The `delay` sub simply causes the program to pause for the specified number of seconds.